# list comprehension python filter random

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this script:

```
test = [
    'listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online<SP>for<SP>free,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>song,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>putlocker,',
    '<SP>download<SP>'+tags+'<SP>song,',
    'listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>free<SP>streaming,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>song<SP>free,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online<SP>song,',
    '<SP>download<SP>'+tags+'<SP>full<SP>song,',
    'listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online<SP>free,',
    '<SP>download<SP>'+tags+'<SP>2013<SP>song,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>online<SP>'+tags+'<SP>for<SP>free,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>free<SP>full<SP>song,',
    'listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online<SP>2013,',
    '<SP>where<SP>to<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+',',
    '<SP>'+tags+'<SP>full<SP>song<SP>online,',
    ''+tags+'<SP>online<SP>free,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>free<SP>2013,',
    ''+tags+'<SP>full<SP>song<SP>online,',
    '<SP>free<SP>streaming<SP>'+tags+',',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>2013,',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+'<SP>free,',
    '<SP>hear<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online,',
    '<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online,',
    'hear<SP>'+tags+',',
    '<SP>listen<SP>'+tags+',',
    '<SP>'+tags+'<SP>free,',
    '<SP>free<SP>'+tags+',',
    '<SP>'+tags+'<SP>online,',
    '<SP>online<SP>'+tags+',',
    '<SP>'+tags+',']
random.shuffle(test)

scris = [x for x in test if len(x) <= 30]
scris_fisiere = scris[0:7]
row_test.append(allitems)
fisier_text_tags.writerow(row_test)
```

As you can see it randomize and writes only the results that have a 30 character long to a csv file, what i want it to do is to write a certain string "whatever" if the string are longer then 30 characters. Now it writes only the results that are under 30 character long, if the results are 3 strings, it only writes from 0 to 2 like [0:2] and so on.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please, its not clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Indeed, what I understood is that in list comprehension you want to replace the string with another, if it is > 30 characters long, but after that I am completely lost. Maybe you should make the example list shorter and fully executable (what is the value of tags ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
scris = [x for x in test if len(x) <= 30]
```

with

```
scris = [len(x) <= 30 and x or 'whatever' for x in test]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember about marking the answer as correct.